# In TableViewController, the data displayed is wrong

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

Before the addition of the below code

[image: The list shows name and number]

After addition of the following lines of code

```
self.tableView.register(ContactListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContactCell")  
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

number disappears.

[image: After the addition of code]

Comment: BTW! I like the names in list.

Comment: I guess you forgot to add bottom constraint to the lowest control in your cell.

Comment: If you are given self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension like this, make sure that the constraints for all components inside cell is given, specially top, bottom constraints

Comment: @TheTiger, lol. But the constraints have been added.

Comment: @Rohi - the constraints have been added.

While debugging it was found that the 2nd label i.e cell.detailTextLabel is 'nil'

Comment: @RasiqKhan, detailTextLabel outlet is connected to ContactListTableViewCell?

Comment: @Rohi, yes It has been connected.

Comment: @RasiqKhan If this is a custom cell then you might be confused with your label. `cell.detailTextLabel` is the default detail label of `UITableViewCell` and not the label you are looking for.

Comment: @RasiqKhan, change the name of detail label and check again

Comment: @TheTiger I renamed the label, but yet I face the same issue.

Comment: @RasiqKhan Have you checked the text you are passing to number `label` is not `empty` or `nil`?

Comment: @TheTiger yes I did, it's not empty or nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you try yo register the cell? If the information it's shows well on the first case means that you have asociated the cell on the storyboard. If you register the cell on code you have to initiate labels on cell class, if yo don't, the labels can be nil. Remove the registration line and try again

Answer (score 0):

where your numbers are showing in first screenshot check that you have provided a bottom constraint to that label.

1.if you dont give bottom constraint then this will happen which is in your first screenshot

[without bottom constraint to last outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FOyl.png)

if u give the bottom constraint to your second label which is showing the number

[Bottom Constraint to label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRwfc.png)

you will get this output
 [final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN25M.png)